# bash perl \z doesn't work

Tags: bash, perl, regex

I have this text file or sdout:

```
text1
text2
text1
text2
text1
text2
```

I have this code:

```
perl -pe "s/text2\n\z/text3/s" text.txt #Note the modifier "/s"
```

I with \z expect him to understand that this is the last line before the eof and consequently I expect:

```
text1
text2
text1
text2
text1
text3
```

But instead it returns:

```
text1
text3text1
text3text1
text3 #without final newline
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I have adopted is:

```
perl -0pe 's/text2\s*$/text3\n/' text.txt
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1108992)

Comment: I have already accepted the answer

Comment: But you posted this as another answer. This looks like a comment to the accepted answer.

Comment: No, this is the solution that i have adopted.

Comment: please note that the code of my answer is different.

Comment: Since there are 2 delete requests for this useful answer which serves mainly to me, seems that I have not been heard in the comments. I repeat. This answer is completely different from the other answers, okay? I put it as an accepted answer, so maybe you will understand.

Answer (score 6):

The command line option `-p` means that the file is processed line by line, i.e. what you do is basically:

```
while (<>) {
     s/text2\n\z/text3/s;
     print $_
}
```

Therefore the `\z` does not match the end of all input data but the end of each line.

What you likely need is not to use `-p` but instead read the full file and replace only the end. Note that the regex can be simplified by just using `$` and `/s` and `\z` are not needed:

```
perl -e 'local $/; (my $x = <>) =~s{text2$}{text3}; print $x' text.txt
```

Comment: You can explain this syntax please?

Comment: @MarioPalumbo: can you please describe what exactly you don't understand on this syntax?

Comment: Sorry LOL, I not have understand the meaning of assignment var = "<>" and the meaning of "$/"

Comment: @MarioPalumbo: `local $/` sets `$/` implicitly to undef . `$/` is the INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR which by default is newline but is now changed to undef - which means that `<>` slurps in the whole file. See `perldoc perlvar` for details, which also includes examples with similar code as I've used.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to slurp in the entire file. Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lpe 's{text2}{text3} if eof ' in_file
```

Prints:

```
text1
text2
text1
text2
text1
text3
```